# Calculate $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\sum (a_i + b_i)$ with $ a_i \geq u$ and $b_i \geq v$ maximizes

Tags: algorithms

I have two datasets $A$ and $B$:

$A = \{1, 5, -34, 34.34323, -23.5444, 9.43, ....\}$
$B = \{-0.5, 44, -0.243, -3455, 2.22221, -23.23, ....\}$

Those datasets contain a big amount of "random" numbers (They are actually not random, but their source does not matter for this question). Both datasets always have the same size.

Now I need to calculate two numbers $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\sum (a_i + b_i)$ with $ a_i \geq u$ and  $b_i \geq v$ reaches the biggest possible value.

For clarification: Say $a_3 \geq u$ but $b_3 < v$. Then $(a_3 + b_3)$ is **not** included in the sum. That is meant by $ a_i \geq u$ and  $b_i \geq v$.

Does an algorithm for the solution to this problem already exist? If not, I am open for ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each pair of elements, $(a_{i},b_{i})$, you can calculate the sum of all the $(a_j+b_j)$ where $a_{j}$ and $b_{j}$ are both greater than or equal to $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$. So an algorithm could look like:

```
largest_pair = 0
largest_value = -∞
for each i:
    for each j:
        total = 0
        if(a[j] >= a[i] & b[j] >= b[i])
            total += a[j] + b[j]
    if(total>largest_value)
        largest_value = total
        largest_pair = i
u = a[largest_pair]
v = b[largest_pair]
output u,v
```

This algorithm is $O(n^2)$ but is easily adaptable to n-variables, and there should be some shortcuts that could speed it up

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm can be solved in $O(n \log^2 n)$ time.  The basic approach is to use [Aidan Connelly's algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/67825/755), except we'll speed up the inner loop so the inner loop takes only $O(\log n)$ time instead of $O(n)$ time.  The solution involves a [sweepline algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm), [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), and other tricks.

---

**Prefix sums.** First, as a warmup, let's note that we can build a data structure that given a set $Y=\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ of points supports the following operations:

- PrefixSum($y$): given $y$, return $\sum_{y_i \ge y, y_i \in Y} y_i$.
- Insert($y$): given $y$, add it to the set $Y$ of points stored in the data structure.

I'll show how to perform both queries in $O(\log n)$ time.

In particular, we can store the points $Y$ in a balanced binary search tree with each point $y_i$ in a leaf of the tree.  We store numbers in the nodes of the tree.  Initially, each leaf receives a number corresponding to the point stored in it, and each internal node is 0.

When we run Insert($y$), we insert a new leaf for the point $y$ (in the correct location, so the leaves are in sorted order), then we find a collection of disjoint subtrees whose union is the set of leaves $y_i$ where $y_i<y$, and add $y_i$ to the root of each of those subtrees.  Notice that any such consecutive interval of leaves can be covered by $O(\log n)$ disjoint subtrees, so the Insert operation runs in $O(\log n)$ time.

To answer PrefixSum($y$), we sum all the numbers on the path from the root to the leaf for $y$ and return that sum.  Since it's a balanced tree, this also runs in $O(\log n)$ time.

---

**Persistence.** Now we can turn this data structure into a [(partially) persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), using standard path copying techniques.

Now, given a version number (timestamp) $t$ and a number $y$, we can compute the answer to PrefixSum($y$) for version $t$ of the data structure.  This can be done in $O(\log n)$ time.  Also, we can perform the operation Insert($y$) on the latest version ($t$), obtaining a new version ($t+1$), in $O(\log^2 n)$ time.  After doing $n$ inserts, the final data structure will have size $O(n \log n)$.

---

**Sweepline.** Now, let's apply this infrastructure to your problem.  Assume the points $(a_i,b_i)$ are sorted first by increasing $a_i$ and then ties resolved by increasing $b_i$.  We'll sweep leftwards, from $(a_n,b_n)$ to $(a_1,b_1)$; when we visit $(a_i,b_i)$, we'll perform Insert($b_i$) into the persistent data structure at that time.  Let's think of $a_i$ as the "version number" for the persistent data structure: given $a_i$, we can find the version of the data structure right after $(a_i,b_i)$ was processed.

Notice that given any $a_j$ and any $b_k$, we can now look up the version corresponding to $a_j$ and perform the PrefixSum($b_k$) operation.  This will return the value of $\sum_{a_i \ge a_j, b_i \ge b_k} a_i + b_i$.  This operation takes $O(\log n)$ time.  So, we can just do this operation $n$ times, once for each pair $a_j,b_j$ that appears in the original list, similar to Aidan Connelly's algorithm.

How long does this take?  Sorting the data can be done in $O(n \log n)$ time.  Building the persistent data structure takes $O(n \log^2 n)$ time, as we perform the Insert operation $n$ times and each instance takes $O(\log^2 n)$ time.  Finally, we perform $n$ PrefixSum lookups, each of which takes $O(\log n)$ time, so that stage takes $O(n \log n)$ time.  The total running time is thus $O(n \log^2 n)$ time.

---

**General remarks.** This technique of combining persistent data structures and a sweepline method is a useful one in computational geometry problems, especially when working in 2D.  See also [Using persistence on a constant database](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/62561/755) and [What classes of data structures can be made persistent?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18262/755).